# When is the lifting correspondence an isomorphism of groups?

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $p:E\to B$ be a covering map, and let $b_0\in B$. Chose $e_0$ such that $p(e_0)=b_0$. Given an element $[f]\in \pi_{1}(B,b_0)$, let $\tilde{f}$ denote the lifting of $f$ to a path in E which begins at $e_0$. Let $g([f])$ denote the end point of $\tilde{f}(1)$ of $\tilde{f}$. Then $g$ is a well defined set map $$g:\pi_{1}(B,b_0)\to p^{-1}(b_0)$$(This is what I mean by the lifting correspondence.)

I am aware of the following:

$\textbf{Theorem:}$ If $E$ is simply connected, then $g$ is a bijection.

My question is, does this imply that $g$ is a group isomorphism?  If not, when is this the case?

Thanks,

Comment: What group structure do you have in mind for $p^{-1}(b_0)$?  I don't see any obvious group structure - just an action of the group $\pi_1(B, b_0)$ on this set which is a free action if $E$ is simply connected.

Comment: I suppose I didn't think it through that clearly - sorry about that.  How about the structure inherited if B is given as the quotient of E by some group G of homeomorphisms of E?

Comment: Nevermind, I see now.  Thank you.

Comment: The other fun fact (which is not as useful, but easier to see) is that you immediately know $\pi_1(B,b_0)$ if you get very lucky and the size of the fiber is prime or something like 15.

Comment: Good point, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $g$ is a group isomorphism. But in order for this statement to make any sense, we first need to define the group structure on $p^{-1}(b_0)$!

One sensible way to do this is as follows. Let $H$ be the group of *deck transformations* for the covering $p : E \to B$. In other words, each element $h \in H$ is a homeomorphism $h : E \to E$ that is compatible with the projection $p : E \to B$, i.e. that satisfies $p \circ h = p$. It is immediate from this definition that every $h \in H$ sends $e_0$ to some point in $ p^{-1}(b_0)$, and with more work (see Hatcher pages 70-71), one can verify that this correspondence between the elements of $H$ and the points in $p^{-1}(b_0)$ is one-to-one and onto. Having thus identified the set $p^{-1}(b_0)$ with the group $H$, it is now meaningful to ask whether or not your map $g : \pi_1(B, b_0) \to p^{-1}(b_0)$ is a group isomorphism, and the answer is yes.

As I mentioned, details of this are provided in Hatcher on pages 70-71, though you may as well prove it yourself. You already know that $g$ is a bijection, so it only remains to check that $g$ is a group homomorphism, and this follows by an argument using uniqueness of path lifts. A few months ago, I wrote [an answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2206920/e-oversetp-longrightarrowx-covering-space-connected-and-locally-path-con/2206983#2206983) about a more general version of this result - see the fourth bullet point in that answer for a hint on how to complete the proof.

Comment: Thank you.  Sorry for not being more clear with my question.